# Problems with script to parse "control" file

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am writing a function to parse debian control files to get a packages build dependancies.  Below is said function, which isn't working.

Debian control files are delimited only by certain "titles" (i.e.: `Build-Depends:`) which are always followed by a colon (`:`).  This leds to the possibility of multiple dependencies being listed on multiple lines that don't have the `Build-Depends` title on that same line (otherwise I already would have this working).

The specific problem I am seeing is that I am getting "command not found" errors from the grep line. The "commands" are words/text from the control file. My knowledge on scripting is limited. I used "google" to piece this together, so I would definitely appreciate any hints.

```
function FindDep ()
{
  CheckVar=0
  echo "Running Find Depend."
  ControlPath=$TmpBuild/Deb-ConfFiles/$1/debian/control
  cat $ControlPath | while read line ;  
  do
    TempVar=`grep Build-Depends $line`
    if [ "$TempVar" != "" ]; then
       BuildDep=`sed s/Build-Depends://g $TempVar | sed s/Build-Depends-Indep\://g | grep -o '[a-z]*[-]*[a-z]*'`
       CheckVar=1
    elif [ $CheckVar == 1 ]; then
        TempVar=`grep : $line`
        if [ "TempVar" != "" ]; then   
           BuildDep="$BuildDep `sed s/Build-Depends://g $TempVar | sed s/Build-Depends-Indep\://g | grep -o '[a-z]*[-]*[a-z]*'`"
        else
           CheckVar=0
        fi
    fi
  done
  echo "Here is what is listed as dep for " $1 "--" $BuildDep
  for y in $BuildDep; do
    echo $y
    IsInstalled="dpkg -s $y | grep Status"
    if [ "$IsInstalled" == "" ]; then
      echo "installing " $y
      dpkg -i $y > /dev/null 2>&1
      if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
        apt-get -f --force-yes --yes install >/dev/null 2>&1
      fi
      dpkg -i $y > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
  done
  echo "Ending Find Depend"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by escaping every line referencing variables, for example, turn this...

```
ControlPath=$TmpBuild/Deb-ConfFiles/$1/debian/control
```

to this:

```
ControlPath="$TmpBuild/Deb-ConfFiles/$1/debian/control"
```

This is why:

```
$ y=hello world
bash: world: command not found

$ y="hello world"

$ cat $y       
cat: hello: No such file or directory
cat: world: No such file or directory

$ cat "$y"
cat: hello world: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I gave it a try and unfortunately it made no difference.  Anything else I should look at?